# Install USB iBurst Driver

Tags: software-installation

I am struggling to install my iBurst USB modem so I can access the internet.

Comment: Have you tried https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Iburst ? Update the question if that didn't work, or if you have problems following the instructions there.

Comment: I have Showed how to get iburst up and running Here <br/> Follow This Link http://askubuntu.com/a/366097/207851 I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you don't need a driver, it's already baked into the kernel. Right-click on the network manager applet first (screenshot 1), and select Edit Connections. Choose the Add button on the DSL tab (screenshot 2). Then insert a name of the connection and tick the 'Connect automatically' box (screenshot 3). Then you need to fill in the details you will have received from iBurst when you set up your account.

PS - I did this at my brother's house in Joburg a few years ago so my memory is a bit flaky :-)

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

[image: screenshot 3]

Answer (score 0):

iBurst USB Modem Installation

Download ''Source code for iBurst driver in DKMS format'' (make sure the add-on is ticked) from the Ubuntu Software Center on your Ubuntu desktop with a WI-FI connection to the Internet. After it has installed plug your USB modem in and open the Terminal application and type ''pppoeconf'' (no inverted commas), then follow the steps and it should work. You can also download ''eyeburst'' from the Ubuntu Software Center to see your signal status but it is not necessary.

Comment: I have tried both things you guys said but it still doesn't want work. Just to clarify I have a iBurst USB Modem and work on Ubuntu 13.04. user142275 I know there are drivers for the iBurst modem. Have downloaded them and tried to install them but with no luck