# Iburst 13.04 not working

Tags: 13.04

Has anyone has managed to install the iBurst USB drivers? I went through the steps and when I want to start the connection I get the following error:

```
Plugin rp-pppoe.so loaded.
/usr/sbin/pppd: in file /etc/ppp/peers/dsl-provider: unrecognized option ''
```

Comment: Please describe the steps you went through

Answer (score 1):

These following steps always work for me:

1. Get the PPA and install:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ginggs/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install ibdriver-dkms
   ```
2. reboot

   (The above comes from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Iburst)

**Roaringpenguin**

1. download and install roaringpenguin:

   - Download rp-pppoe-3.11.tar.gz from http://www.roaringpenguin.com/products/pppoe
   - For instructional purposes I will download and save to the desktop.
   - Right Click and select extract here.
   - Open up a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) and type in the following.
2. `cd Desktop/rp-pppoe-3.11`
3. `sudo ./go`
4. Enter your PPPoE user name eg `emailaddress@iburst.co.za`.
5. Enter the Ethernet interface -enter `ib0`.
6. Do you want the link to come up on demand - enter `no`.

   PS. if you type `yes` this usually searches for network interfaces when booting into ubuntu a you end up waiting for a while before it boots up. I don't recommend using `yes`.
7. Enter the DNS information here: enter `server`.
8. Please enter your PPPoE password: enter Your iburst password.
9. Choose a type of firewall (0-2): Enter `1`. This is fine for a single computer
10. The summary should look something like this:

    ```
    ** Summary of what you entered **

    Ethernet Interface: ib0
    User name:          youriburstemail@iburst.co.za
    Activate-on-demand: No
    DNS addresses:      Supplied by ISP's server
    Firewalling:        STANDALONE
    ```
11. enter `y`.

To start up Iburst type:

```
sudo pppoe-start
```