# My pc freezes when I connect to the internet with my iBurst USB modem

Tags: usb-modem

I'm having some trouble with iBurst USB modem. I followed [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Iburst), and now it seems I can connect to the internet, but when I try to connect my whole desktop freezes. When I boot into Ubuntu with my modem connected all is well until I try to open Firefox then my desktop freezes as well. I used Graham Inngs' ibdriver in DKMS format solution and it worked apart from the freezing. Graham Inggs made a patch for this problem for older Linux versions but I can't seem to find anything compatible with 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Use: 
sudo pppoeconf
pon dsl-provider

Using dsl-provider to start the connection always freezes Ubuntu.

Instead Install and use **Roaringpenguin**
I have Showed how to get iburst up and running Here

Follow This Link https://askubuntu.com/a/366097/207851

I hope this helps you

Comment: I followed your link , but when I get to the roaringpenguin installation process at step 3 > sudo ./go < i get the following error > sudo: ./go: command not found <. I'm very new to Ubuntu and find myself stuck. Sorry. Can it be that a previous attempt to fix my networking problems is interfering with your solution?

Comment: Another method is to simply open up the terminal write  "sudo" without quotations and then drag and drop the "go" file in to the terminal and press enter.